# Neo4j Cypher query and node parameters instead of relationship values

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

In my Neo4j, SDN4 project I have a following entities:

`Decision`, `Criterion`, `Vote`

Every Decision can have a Vote on a different Criteria.

Right now I use a following Cypher query in order to sort Decisions by avg. vote weights of a selected Criteria (`{criteriaIds}` parameter represents `Set<Long>` of `Criterion` IDs):

```
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision) 
WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId} 
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[vg:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c) 
WHERE id(c) IN {criteriaIds} 
WITH c, childD, (vg.avgVotesWeight * (CASE WHEN c IS NOT NULL THEN coalesce({criteriaCoefficients}[toString(id(c))], 1.0) ELSE 1.0 END)) as weight, vg.totalVotes as totalVotes 
WITH * MATCH (childD)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User)  
RETURN ru, u, childD AS decision, toFloat(sum(weight)) as weight, toInt(sum(totalVotes)) as totalVotes 
ORDER BY  weight DESC, childD.name ASC 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 10
```

Right now I'm not satisfied with a performance of this query so I'd like to reduce a data cardinality during the query execution.

In order to do this, instead of storing every `avgVotesWeight` as a property of relationship between `Decision` and `Criterion` I plan to store this value as a property of `Decision` node itself.

For example I have a following nodes:

```
Decision1(uid = 1)

Criterion1(uid = 1)
Criterion2(uid = 2)
Criterion3(uid = 3)
```

`Decision1` have a following `avgVotesWeight` on the criteria:

```
Decision1 for Criterion1 = 4.3
Decision2 for Criterion1 = 2.1
Decision3 for Criterion1 = 1.8
```

so I'm going to create a following properties on `Decision1` node:

```
Decision1(CAVW1=4.3, CAVW2=2.1, CAVW3=1.8)
```

where `CAVW` is a plain `String` prefix in order to distinguish these properties from the rest of the `Decision` properties in my SDN4 [Custom Type Converter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference:type-conversion:custom) an `1` or `2` or `3` suffixes are `Criterion` `uid`(I'm passing these `uid` to my Cypher query in `{criteriaIds}` parameter)

So my questions are - Is it a good idea in general? If so, could you please help me to rewrite the mentioned query above in order to use these properties instead of the following old Cypher query:

```
WHERE id(c) IN {criteriaIds} 
WITH c, childD, (vg.avgVotesWeight * (CASE WHEN c IS NOT NULL THEN coalesce({criteriaCoefficients}[toString(id(c))], 1.0) ELSE 1.0 END)) as weight, vg.totalVotes as totalVotes
```

Also, I don't know right now where to keep `vg.totalVotes` values that are currently also stored at the same relationship between `Decision` and `Criterion`. Please advise. Maybe it should be also stored with the same approach like I want to implement for `avgVotesWeight` ? For example I can introduce addition `Decision` properties like `TV1=34`. Is it a good idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whoever may be interested in a similar solution, this is my new working query:

```
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision) 
WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId} 
UNWIND {criteriaIds} AS cid 
WITH childD, (properties(childD)['CAVW' + cid] * (CASE WHEN cid IS NOT NULL THEN coalesce({criteriaCoefficients}[toString(cid)], 1.0) ELSE 1.0 END)) AS weight, properties(childD)['CTV' + cid] AS totalVotes  
WITH * MATCH (childD)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User)  
RETURN ru, u, childD AS decision, toFloat(sum(weight)) as weight, toInt(sum(totalVotes)) as totalVotes 
ORDER BY  weight 
DESC SKIP 0 LIMIT 2
```